# I have a database, if I want to retrieve a field of a specific document I can, but I would like to retrieve a field from the last document updated

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In this way it works, I go to retrieve the field of that document (in this case the extranote), but what if I would only be interested in that field of the last document inserted chronologically?

I looked for similar examples but I wouldn't want just a few options, which I obviously don't know, to add when I create the db.

This model was created to read directly into the database without going through the App:

```
struct WorkoutModel: Identifiable,Codable {
    //var id = UUID().uuidString
    @DocumentID var id : String?
    var extranote : String
    var error: String = ""
}




struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    var deviceCount: Int
    var deviceMake: String
    var deviceModel: String
    var deviceType: String
    let configuration: ConfigurationIntent
    var workoutData: WorkoutModel?
}

func fetchFromDB(completion: @escaping (WorkoutModel)->()){
        let db = Firestore.firestore().collection("devices").document("lEp5impGTGeBmAEisQT")
        
        db.getDocument { snap, err in
            guard let doc = snap?.data() else {
                completion(WorkoutModel(extranote: "", error: err?.localizedDescription ?? ""))
                return
            }
            let extranote = doc["extranote"] as? String ?? ""
            completion(WorkoutModel(extranote: extranote))
        }
    }

func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, 
   completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []
        
        // Generate a timeline consisting of five entries an hour apart, starting 
  from the current date.
        let date = Date()
        let nextUpdate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 5, to:date)!
        
    

fetchFromDB { work in
        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: nextUpdate, deviceCount: 
           deviceCount,deviceMake: deviceMake,deviceModel: deviceModel,deviceType: 
           deviceType, configuration: configuration, workoutData: work)
        entries.append(entry)
        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the ID of the document to update, then you will need to [query the collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#swift_1) for the document.  If you don't have a field in that document that indicates the timestamp of its last update, then you won't be able to make that query at all.  So, you will have to add a field to the document, and make sure it's populated with the current timestamp every time you write it.  Then you can use that field to make the query if you want to update it again later.